# How to insert and center align my logo into my banner?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble to insert my logo inside white banner on top of the page.

The thing you have to look out for in my code is the `header` ID:

```
<div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
</div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Please refer to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hopk91yc/) link:

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this css for logo class:

```
.LogoFF1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header{
 height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto; 
}

#header{
 height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
 font-size:130px;
 position: relative;
}

h2.main {
 font-size: 20px; 
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
 max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
 max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%, rgb(130,140,149) 36%, rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}

.LogoFF1 { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
   <div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
    <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>About</h2>
     <p>
 Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
 </p>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus.
 Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula.
 Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis.
 Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
 </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css to you logo

```
.LogoFF1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header{
 height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto; 
}

#header{
 height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
 font-size:130px;
 position: relative;
}

h2.main {
 font-size: 20px; 
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
 max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
 max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%, rgb(130,140,149) 36%, rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}

.LogoFF1 {
  
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
   <div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
    <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>About</h2>
     <p>
 Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
 </p>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus.
 Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula.
 Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis.
 Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
 </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css in .LogoFF1 class

```
.LogoFF1{
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Add margin-top: 0px

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header{
 height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto; 
}

#header{
 height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
 font-size:130px;
 position: relative;
}
#header p{
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h2.main {
 font-size: 20px; 
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
 max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
 max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%, rgb(130,140,149) 36%, rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
   <div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
    <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>About</h2>
     <p>
 Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
 </p>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus.
 Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula.
 Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis.
 Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
 </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited and updated your JS fiddle

Simply add this:

```
.LogoFF1{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header{
 height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto; 
}

#header{
 height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
 font-size:130px;
 position: relative;
}

h2.main {
 font-size: 20px; 
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
 max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
 max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%, rgb(130,140,149) 36%, rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}

.LogoFF1{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
   <div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
    <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>About</h2>
     <p>
 Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
 </p>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus.
 Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula.
 Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis.
 Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
 </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add this to your CSS code

```
#header{
height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
font-size:130px;
position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or you can add it to your html

```
<div id="header" align="center ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Css

```
.LogoFF1{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #101010;
  
}
.LogoFF1{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:0px;
}
header{
 height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto; 
}

#header{
 height:150px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
 text-shadow: 6px 5px 4px #FF0000;
 font-size:130px;
 position: relative;
}

h2.main {
 font-size: 20px; 
 letter-spacing:1px; 
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px -2px 2px #2050FF,
    -2px 2px 2px #2050FF,
     2px 2px 2px #2050FF;"
}

#section {
 max-width: 960px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#section2 {
 max-width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:4px; 
     margin-top: auto;
     margin-bottom: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 220px;
    text-align: center; 
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
}

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin: 10px left;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

nav.vertical > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav.vertical > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
  background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%, rgb(130,140,149) 36%, rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(181,189,200) 0%,rgb(130,140,149) 36%,rgb(40,52,59) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label:hover,
nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav.vertical > ul > li > label + input {
  display: none;
  visability: hidden;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: #AAAAFF;
}
/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: #DD04FF;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
footer {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}
nav ul {
  nav ul: list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav li a:link {
  text-decoration: none: font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
   <div id="header">
      <p class="LogoFF1">FF1 Site</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="vertical">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="homePage.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="profile.html">Profile</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personalBests.html">Personal Bests</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="links.html">Links</a>
          </li>
    <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <div id="section">
      <article>
        <h2>About</h2>
     <p>
 Hello there, and welcome to FireFalcons personal website!
 </p>
 <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pharetra rutrum massa vitae cursus.
 Integer condimentum sollicitudin tristique. Ut lectus mi, iaculis eget faucibus quis, tincidunt eu ligula.
 Aliquam id ornare dui. Nulla efficitur ipsum vitae magna ultricies placerat ullamcorper ut turpis.
 Ut sed malesuada nibh. Phasellus fringilla ex a eros volutpat consectetur.
 </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <strong>
                Copyright &copy; 2016 Stephen Fawcett, All rights reserved
        </strong>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```